# In C++, why am I finding heap memory accesses to be faster than stack acccesses

Tags: c++, stack, heap-memory, mmu

I've been playing around with a profiler in C++ and noticed something really weird: writing to the heap memory is somehow faster than stack memory?!

Here's the snippet I ran

```
#include <iostream>       // std::cout
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;
const int size = 1000000;
void incStack(){
    int seconds = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        seconds++;
    }
}

void incHeap(){
    int* seconds = new int(0);
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        (*seconds)++;
    }
}

void testCycles(void (*func)(), string funcName){
    int total = 0;
    int count = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
        clock_t t = clock();
        func();
        t = clock() - t;
        // we move the function to the cache on the first call which can possibly give
        // us overhead, so we'll ignore the first call
        if(i != 1){
            total+= t;
            count++;
        }
    }
    cout << funcName << " cycles: " << total/count << endl;
}

int main() {
    testCycles(incStack, "incStack");
    testCycles(incHeap, "incHeap");
    return 0;
}
```

with output

```
incStack cycles: 1997
incHeap cycles: 1487
```

which is pretty significant! I realize that because I'm only accessing one part of memory on the heap, it'll probably always be in cache. If I was accessing many parts of the heap, I assume I'd suffer in performance for all the page swaps to cache I'd incur because memory is likely to be fragmented on the heap. But ignoring all that, the heap should at least have two accesses of memory (one for the address and one for the value of the address) which should take more time than the stack.

But the heap accesses are faster when I ran this code, so am I missing something in C++? I tried compiling on a few compilers and toggled optimizations and got similar results. I'm really confused as to why this would be.

Comment: First question: Is this a fully optimized build you're benchmarking? It's also worth noting that benchmarking it for a few nanoseconds is not a very good benchmark. You really need to lay into this thing, like test for at least 60s for CPU temperatures and "turbo" effects to simmer down. You also need to test them in random order as well, as the first one might just appear to be slow for various reasons.

Comment: Dereferencing a pointer *will* be more painful than doing a straight-up increment. Test this with an address to a stack variable for a more fair comparison.

Comment: Did you check the generated assembly? Did you confirm that the compiler kept the calls to `clock()` around the tested function, rather than reordering these side-effect free calls? Did you verify that the compiler didn't *completely remove* these side effect free calls?

Comment: I think you are measuring noise.

Comment: This code doesn't even compile for me. Where is `size` defined? When do `total` and `count` ever get set to something other than `0`? What is the _actual_ code you've run to perform this benchmark?

Comment: If I do a few small things to this code to make it compile for me and use `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` instead of C-style `clock_t`, then at O3 I get that the stack version [is distinctly faster](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/81d697478003f04f). On my desktop using MSVC, the difference is ~10% in stack's favor at Debug, several orders of magnitude in stack's favor in Release.

Answer (score 0):

Generally memory is memory, the CPU doesn't really distinguish. It does, however, care about how that memory is accessed. In C++ you have three tools for that: values, pointers and references.

Direct values are always going to be the fastest. These might not be stored in memory at all, but registers, and only persisted to memory if/when that's necessary. Incrementing a value in a register is going to be very quick.

Indirect values, like pointers, involve a whole other kind of access. These cannot be stored in registers, they require manipulating a value external to the CPU (core), hopefully in some kind of cache like L1. Once in cache it won't be as slow as main memory, but will *always* be slower than a register.

References are kind of an alias for regular values, so they should perform as well, but this depends on how optimized your code is when it was compiled. Under a heavily optimized build, like `-O3` or equivalent, these can often be shunted around in registers instead of ever actually hitting memory.